# How to get autocompletetextview id?

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

I follow [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-autocompletetextview-example-json/) example to use autocmpletetextview in my project,i want to get id when user select any item,can anyone tell how to get id..

following is json response..so if click on ab then i want to get 1,if i click on abc i want to get 2..

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private AutoCompleteTextView acTextView;
private String idtest;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);

    final SuggestionAdapter adapter=new SuggestionAdapter(this, acTextView.getText().toString());
    acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);


    acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JsonParse jps=new JsonParse();

            /* List<SuggestGetSet> list =jps.getParseJsonWCF(acTextView.getText().toString());

                for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
                {
                  if(list.get(i).getName().equals(acTextView.getText().toString()))

                  idtest=list.get(position).getId();



                }
                   */




            SuggestGetSet  selectedSuggestGetSet = 
                     adapter.getAllUpdatedSuggestion().get(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedSuggestGetSet+acTextView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

adapter

```
public class SuggestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

protected static final String TAG = "SuggestionAdapter";
public List<String> suggestions;
private List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions;

public SuggestionAdapter(Activity context, String nameFilter) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suggestions.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return suggestions.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and
                // returns an ArrayList<GoEuroGetSet>
                new_suggestions =jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                suggestions.clear();
                for (int i=0;i<new_suggestions.size();i++) {
                    suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getName());

                }

                // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults
                // object
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}

public List<SuggestGetSet>  getAllUpdatedSuggestion(){
      return this.new_suggestions;
    }
```

}
response

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","name":"ab"},{"id":"2","name":"abc"},{"id":"3","name":"bc"},{"id":"4","name":"bcd"},{"id":"5","name":"cd"},{"id":"6","name":"cde"},{"id":"7","name":"ef"},{"id":"8","name":"efg"},{"id":"9","name":"hi"},{"id":"10","name":"hig"},{"id":"11","name":"jk"},{"id":"12","name":"jkl"},{"id":"13","name":"mn"},{"id":"14","name":"mno"},{"id":"15","name":"pq"},{"id":"16","name":"pqr"},{"id":"17","name":"st"},{"id":"18","name":"stu"},{"id":"19","name":"vw"},{"id":"20","name":"vwx"},{"id":"21","name":"yz"},{"id":"22","name":"yza"}]}
```

Comment: Which id you want to get?

Comment: the id which i have in my response..

Comment: `the id which i have in my response`: in which response ?

Comment: in that example they get name and id from server see here http://webheavens.com/suggestion.php?name=

Comment: see carefully the method signature: `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,                     int position, long id)` is there an `id`?

Comment: @pskink id which i have in response..that i want when user click on item..see my edited answer..suppose if i click on "ab" i want to get id "1"

Comment: as i said use the last param `id`, why do you think it is passed to `onItemClick` method? BTW you dont need to write that long custom adapter, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: @pskink then in my toast i am getting name..can you tell why?

Comment: because you are showing acTextView.getText() ?

Comment: see http://codeshare.io/2xgvK

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK see edited question...i am getting null on click

Comment: @Lakhan: lots of changes required see my answer for help. let me know still facing any issue in posted issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put one method in adapter

```html
public Int getItemId(int index) {
    return suggestions.get(index).getId();
}
```

Then access it in onItemClick. You will getId from there by
adapter.getItemId(position);

Answer (score 1):

> How to get id of autocompletetextview item?

`new_suggestions` contains all items which want to get on ListView item click. so declare it outside  `getFilter` method for access from other class:

```
private List<String> suggestions;
private List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions ;
....
```

`new_suggestions` initilize it inside `getFilter` method:

```
...
new_suggestions =jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
suggestions.clear();
...
```

Now create a method inside `SuggestionAdapter` :

```
public List<SuggestGetSet>  getAllUpdatedSuggestion(){
  return this.new_suggestions;
}
```

and finally inside `onItemClick` call `getAllUpdatedSuggestion` method:

```
final SuggestionAdapter adapter=new SuggestionAdapter(this,
                                acTextView.getText().toString())
acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and in `onItemClick` method:

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        SuggestGetSet  selectedSuggestGetSet = 
                     adapter.getAllUpdatedSuggestion().get(position);
    }
```

`selectedSuggestGetSet` will contains selected item `name` and `id`

Comment: @Lakhan please, please tell me why do you want to use your so complex code? that crashes again and again? i gave you **WORKING** 30 lines of code, so why? what is so hard in it to understand?

Comment: @pskink your code work well..but my issue was to get id on click of item..but i dint get it from your code too..so again i work on this complex code

Comment: @Lakhan i give up, i already said three times: use the last parameter of onItemClick: long id

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes i tried but in my toast it is not showing id and name

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK see question

Comment: @Lakhan: use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedSuggestGetSet.getName()+" ID "+selectedSuggestGetSet. getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK need your help in paypal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910575/how-to-get-access-token-paypal-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Change your suggestions list to public   :

```
public List<String> suggestions;
```

And then get the desired id in your itemClick method :

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            your id = YourAdapter.suggestions[position].id;

        }
```

Comment: how to set this way..your id = YourAdapter.suggestions[position].id;

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions = jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
```

and make one with `private List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions;` in your adapter